# spring webapp library jars at ear level

Tags: spring, ear, web-applications

My question is

> If I have multiple spring web applications in EAR.
>   Then can I place all spring and
>   related jar files at ear level so that
>   I don't need to duplicate them by
>   placing them in WEB-INF/lib folder.

I tried to find out the answer but couldn't find matching to my case. Experts please tell me what are the pros and cons of this structure, issue that might occur with class loading etc. Or tell me if I am completely wrong about my question.